# How to programmatically parse emails on an Outlook server and execute a script/task

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, scripting

My intranet web application (written in C#/ASP.Net MVC) sends email notifications in certain situations. I would like to intercept replies to such emails and perform actions based on the content of such replies.

I have no preference for scripting language - it could be Powershell, Python, VBA, anything - as long as I can parse the subject and body of the email, I can then alter the database of my web application through this script and pick up changes with an automated task, but I really have no clue where to start. I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

**QUESTION**

How can I intercept emails sent to the Outlook server and perform action based on the content of such emails?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need an inbound email parsing service. I've worked with the one from SendGrid and it will catch any replies to a specific email address, and then post the email contents to an action on a controller in your MVC app. This will give you access to the full email contents and you can process it as needed.

See [Setting up Inbound Parse](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook/)